# Is this question involving `Hindu census` and `conversions` on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Today, I asked a question on our main site about the decision by Government, if any, that affects the Hindu census. I believed the question is on-topic for our site as the decisions like such can surely affect the Hindu population in India. The question is

[Did mother Teresa ask to allow to Christianise Arunachal Pradesh to receive Bharat Ratna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/51501/did-mother-teresa-ask-to-allow-to-christianise-arunachal-pradesh-to-receive-bhar)

If you read the body of the question, the answer to this question surely has an impact on Hindus in India. But after a user commented

> How is this related to Hinduism question as per the site?

I revisited the scope of our site

> You've come to the right place if you have questions about:
>
> Hindu scripture and stories.
>
> Academic questions about Hindu philosophical thought.
>
> Questions about Hindu practices.
>
> **Historical questions about the evolution of Hinduism.**
>
> Different sects of Hinduism and their beliefs.

I believed that the question falls into the bolded portion as the bolded portion can be interpreted in a couple of ways: Changes in the interpretation of scriptures and **events that impact Hindus**.

I feel that the question is on-topic as we can discuss the events that impact Hindus even if it involves the decision of the political parties, governments, courts, or individuals.

Please share your opinions on it.

*Note:* At the same time, I feel that our main site should not become a platform to discuss events in Indian history that are unrelated to Hinduism or as a platform to confront politics.  Religious conversions by several means are rampant in India from centuries and many elevated people like Vivekananda categorically rejected it.

Comment: " If yes, did the Congress Government, which was in the power, allow the spread of Christianity in Arunachal Pradesh?" <= To me this looks like a question on Indian political history. And it's not even about Hinduism. It is rather about spread of Christianity in A.P.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Can't we view it as an attempt to convert **Hindus** into Christianity? I mean can't we view it as an attack on Hindus by mass conversions?

Comment: IMO it is fit for History.SE @hanugm

Comment: Conversions on Hindus is political.

Comment: @Rickross Okay.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti Okay.

Comment: Then someone please migrate it to History SE if possible.